# WPGLOBUS plugin show both languages on my slider

Tags: wordpress

> text show in english and in french even if i change the text in both
>   language in the custom menu

I've checked on WPGlobus doc and it says :

```
// Wrong. Prints 'Hello' regardless of the user's language.
echo 'Hello';
// Correct. Translators can supply the translation of 'Hello'.
echo __( 'Hello', 'my-text-domain' );
```

but it doesnt work

Comment: https://imgur.com/328fQRq

Comment: It seems to be a problem due to the filter
 
https://wpglobus.com/documentation/wpglobus-compatibility-with-themes-and-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the place in the code where the text is printed on the screen.
   It should say something like `echo $something;`.
2. Surround `$something` with a filter: `echo apply_filters('the_title', $something);`
3. If it helps (it should), tell the slider's author to include that change in their next release.